# Java SWT Slider.getMaximum() equals 100, but you can only drag it up to 90

Tags: java, slider, swt

If you create a `Slider` (org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Slider) then call `getMaximum()` on it, the value is 100. But when you actually try dragging the Slider to its maximum value, it only reaches 90.

I can work round this problem:

```
sl.setSelection(sl.getMaximum());   // sl.getMaximum() is 100   
int actualMax = sl.getSelection();  // should be 100, but is actually 90
```

But something definitely seems to be wrong, no?

Comment: Check the width of the slider (the increment).  I'm guessing that the slider stops before the maximum to include the increment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you know `Slider` is nothing but `ScrollBar` widget,the maximum value that you set is equal to  **max_value+thumb_value** value.

Try this code:

```
  final Slider slider = new Slider(shell, SWT.NONE);
  slider.setMaximum(100);
  slider.setMinimum(0);
  slider.setThumb(20);

  slider.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {

    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        System.out.println( slider.getSelection()  +"   "+ slider.getThumb());
    }

    @Override
    public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
  });
```

Comment: I didn't know that. But thank you. So the maximum value you can actually drag the slider to is `sl.getMaximum() - sl.getThumb()`. I still think it would be much more natural for the maximum value you can drag it to to be  `sl.getMaximum()`.

Answer (score 1):

I can also observe this behavior on Windows 7 with SWT 3.6.1 and SWT 4.2.1.

A simple but somehow dissatisfying workaround would be to use:

```
sl.setMaximum(110);
```

Then the values range from  `0` to `100`.

Comment: This does **not** work in general (since it depends on the thumb value - see my answer for details).

Comment: Also, the middle of the slider will now be 55.

Answer (score 1):

Although the provided answers helped to solve the problem, it still took a while for me to implement it correctly. If you want to make the values `0-100` selectable with your slider, you should do:

```
// we want to have the values 0-100
slider.setMaximum(100 + slider.getThumb());
// this now returns the selected value, which can be from 0-100
slider.getSelection();
```